# How to deploy a react js app on a No-CPanel VPS which will be using nodejs/mongodb in the backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vps

I have purchased a no-cPanel VPS on [hioxindia](https://hioxindia.com). I want to deploy a react app (using just the build files) on the server. I have installed node js on the server. And have copied the build files on it using `FileZilla`. I found a few ways to do it using express js, but no idea on how to do it using just the build files. Can anyone provide info on what is the procedure to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy it using `nginx` or `nginx and docker` depends on your preferences or client requirements. Here are some good tutorials of how that could be done.

All you need to do is you need to access to server with ssh from you terminal:

```
ssh user@ip
```

Write you password and then you can do the following commands from your terminal

https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7

https://medium.com/@tiangolo/react-in-docker-with-nginx-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-including-testing-8cc49d6ec305